# Why does my Datatable not have any results coming in?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, dataset

I am sort of new to working with datasets, adapters, datatables, etc... So I believe this would qualify as a noob question.

I create Dataset in visual studio using the visual designer (the file with the .xsd extention). I there I defined a DataTable that I named "Courses". I populated this table via the designer using a sql server query, so I know I have my data connection correct.

In my code I am testing out how to instatiate that DataTable and then map the columns in it to a local class I call Course.cs. Here is the method:

```
MyContext ctx = new MyContext();

SqlConnection conn = 
    new SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=****;Password=****");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"select * from stuff", conn);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
MyDataSet ds = new MyDataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
da.Fill(ds);
DataTable courses = ds.Courses;

IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
   from course in courses.AsEnumerable()
   select course;
foreach (var course in query)
{
    Course localCourse = new Course();
    localCourse.CourseCode = course.Field<string>("CourseCode");
    ctx.Courses.Add(localCourse);
}
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I am not getting any errors, it will run the code fine, but since the 'query' variable does not have anything in it, it is not making the new objects I want and mapping the values.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the quick responses! When I add the line of code:

```
da.Fill(ds);
```

it give me this exception:

```
{"The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'."}
```

Which confuses me because I am not wanting to create a select command, I though that was already in my datatable?

**Edit Two**

I have done what was suggested, and it makes sense what I need to do, but I am still getting no results (No errors anymore though..). If I run the same query on the same connection string I can get results, any ideas?

**Edit Three!**

Here is the raw and ugly query that I am using to populate the datatable. Like I said, the results come in fine if I do it in SSMS.

```
select 
s.AdClassSchedId,
rtrim(s.code) + 
CASE WHEN (isnull(s.section,'') <> '') 
THEN '-S' + s.section 
ELSE '' END as CourseCode,
s.descrip +
CASE WHEN (isnull(s.section,'') <> '') 
THEN ' - Section ' + s.section 
ELSE '' END as CourseName,
s.AdTeacherId, 
s.StartDate,
s.EndDate,
s.DateLstMod as ClassSchedLastModified,
t.AdTermId
from adclasssched s 
inner join adclassschedterm t on s.adclassschedid = t.adclassschedid
where s.active = 1
```

Comment: you haven't filled the data table. please read up on SQLDataAdapter. here's a usefull link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/462730/Five-different-overloads-of-the-DataAdapter-Fill-m

Comment: is that work for you ??

Comment: @PranayRana I appreciate your thorough answer, but I am still not seeing data in my query variable... posted another edit to my question.

Comment: @davidisawesome- same query retuning data in database ???????

Comment: @davidisawesome - check the updated answer again...

Comment: @PranayRana just posted it

Comment: @davidisawesome - make sure than same query is returns you data when you run it in sqlquery window ....i.e. in sql server direcly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Way1**

If you are using sqlcommand to fill dataset object than you need to open and close connection like this

```
SqlConnection nwindConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=northwind");

SqlCommand selectCMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers", nwindConn);
selectCMD.CommandTimeout = 30;

SqlDataAdapter custDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
custDA.SelectCommand = selectCMD;

nwindConn.Open();

DataSet custDS = new DataSet();
custDA.Fill(custDS, "Customers");

nwindConn.Close();
```

[Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

---

**Way2**

Update for you

```
// Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
string queryString = 
  "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

DataSet customers = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");
```

[Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx)

---

**Before update**

Fill your dataset object which not here in you code

```
MyDataSet ds = new MyDataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
//fill datase object ds
//DataAdapter.Fill(ds)
DataTable courses = ds.Courses;
```

---

for this error

```
{"The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'."}
```

do as below , as error said set select command

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
adapter.SelectCommand = command;
```

Full source : [SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx)

Comment: @davidisawesome - check my update for your error and also visit link for more details...

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the diligent responses, code is a bit ugly this way, but it works!

Answer (score 4):

I don't see you calling fill on the adapter anywhere?

There should be a line of code somewhere in there that looks like...

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from courses", mySqlConnection);

da.Fill(ds);
```

Additionally, you need to set the select command of the data adapter to the sql statement you intend to run from the database.

Comment: So even though my datatable was created using a sql query, I need to run that same query on the data adapter?

Comment: Creating the table at design time is not the same as setting the connection and sql statement at runtime. If you used the wizard to generate the dataset at design time, that sql statement was just used to build the structure of the dataset. You would need to set the select command text property on the designer to that same sql as well.